# Webpack 5 & sass: mini-css-extract-plugin cannot resolve fonts

Tags: webpack, sass, mini-css-extract-plugin

There is my extremly simple `test.scss` file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Roboto;
    src: url("../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    font-weight: 400;
}

.test {
    display: flex;
    font-family: Roboto;
}
```

And this is my webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ],
    entry: './src/sass/test.scss',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/css/'),
        filename: '[name].css',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

When running webpack it throws the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/sass/test.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
```

So the mini-css-extract-plugin has a problem with my font. Already tried different approaches but anything worked.
I am happy about any solution. It does not seem that easy to compile sass in css using webpack ...

Comment: Shouldn't you define a rule for a *font module* as well? [Docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts).

Comment: Tried this already, but still got the error message.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Make sure the font path is correct.